# Combine arrays with common keys for MYSQL update

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have four $_POST arrays generated from multiple rows of a table

```
$event_id_array = $_POST['event_id'];
$booth_array = $_POST['booth']; 
$parking_array = $_POST['parking']; 
$load_in_array = $_POST['load_in'];
```

I would like to rearrange the arrays to be keyed by $event_id_array as the key of each of the other arrays = an 'event_id'

Arrays are:

```
$event_id_array =
array(52) {
  ["'3'"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["'5'"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["'7'"]=>
  string(1) "7"
  ["'8'"]=>
  string(1) "8"
}

$booth_array =
array(52) {
  ["'3'"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["'5'"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["'7'"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["'8'"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

$parking_array =
array(52) {
  ["'3'"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["'5'"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["'7'"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["'8'"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

$load_in_array = 
array(52) {
  ["'3'"]=>
  string(4) "1:00"
  ["'5'"]=>
  string(4) "2:00"
  ["'7'"]=>
  string(4) "1:15"
  ["'8'"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

I would like the new array to be efficiently update a MySQL database and was thinking a structure of the following would be best:

```
array(
 event_id[3] => array(
  'booth' => "1",
  'parking' => "1",
  'load_in' => "1:00"),
 event_id[5] => array(
  'booth' => "2",
  'parking' => "2",
  'load_in' => "2:00"),
event_id[7] => array(
  'booth' => "4",
  'parking' => "",
  'load_in' => "1:15"),
event_id[8] => array(
  'booth' => "",
  'parking' => "",
  'load_in' => ""),
)
```

or any other way to easily update multiple records easily

Comment: You can define that structure in your form inputs: `<input name="event_id[3][booth]"...` and `<input name="event_id[3][parking]"...` or any other structure.

Comment: Check your values as there seems to be an extra set of quotes in each key - `"'3'"`

Comment: Thank you @abraCadaver that is it....so simple and got really stuck on it.

Comment: @NigelRen Thank you I had an extra set of ' ' in my inputs